# Convert one row of data in sql server to columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query that outputs just one row of data. I want to convert that row to column and the column to row.

My original query

```
------------------------
ID     Name     Desc
------------------------
1     Nisha     Some desc
```

what I need

```
--------------------------
FieldName     FieldValue
--------------------------
ID            1
Name          Nisha
Description   Some Desc
```

Comment: why you want to do that???

Comment: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:419593546543 and https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1113915 
these links might help u...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @colNum int, @i int = 1, @a nvarchar(4000)
select @colNum=count(COLUMN_NAME) from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'

set @a = '
            declare  @tempTable  table
            (
                 slno       int
                ,field      nvarchar(100)
                ,value      nvarchar(100)
            )

            insert into @tempTable (slno,field)
            select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ordinal_position asc),COLUMN_NAME

            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''YourTable''

            declare @p nvarchar(100)
        '



declare @colname nvarchar(100)

while @i<=@colNum
begin
    select @colname =a.COLUMN_NAME from (select COLUMN_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION

                                                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                                WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'
                                        )as a 
                                        where a.ORDINAL_POSITION = @i
    set @a = @a +   ' 
                          select @p='+@colname+' from YourTable

                        update  @tempTable set 
                        value = @p 
                        where slno = '+CONVERT(nvarchar(5), @i)
                    +'  


                    '


    set @i=@i+1
end



set @a = @a + '   select * from @tempTable'

declare  @tempTable  table
            (
                 slno       int
                ,field      nvarchar(100)
                ,value      nvarchar(100)
            )

insert into @tempTable exec (@a)

select * from YourTable

select * from @tempTable
```